# How to flip part of an image horizontal with PHP GD

Tags: php, image, gd

I am creating an image with parts from another image. I use imagecopy to but the "parts" togheter. Some parts need to be flipped horizontal.

For example this part:

```
imagecopy($output, $input, 0,8, 44,20, 4,12);
```

How do i flip this part horizontal??

I have tried this:

```
imagecopy($output, $input, (0 - 1),8, 44,20, 4,12);
```

But it does not work.

I have searched for ages, but cant find anything that works

My script looks like this:

```
$input = imagecreatefrompng($image_file);
$output = imagecreatetruecolor(50, 40);

imagecopy($output, $input, 4,8, 20,20, 8,14);
imagecopy($output, $input, 12,8, 44,20, 4,14);
imagecopy($output, $input, 4,20, 4,20, 4,14);
imagecopy($output, $input, 8,28, 4,20, 4,14);
imagecopy($output, $input, 32,8, 52,20, 4,14);
imagecopy($output, $input, 24,20, 12,20, 4,14);
imagecopy($output, $input, 28,28, 12,20, 4,14); 
imagecopy($output, $input, 4,0, 40,8, 8,9);
imagecopy($output, $input, 24,0, 56,8, 8,9);


header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($output);

imagedestroy($output);
imagedestroy($input);
```

Comment: Hi Martin, i found a function that flipped the image, the function used this to flip:
`imagecopy($dest, $img, ($width - $i - 1),0, $i,0, 1,$height);` but id does not make sense to me..

Comment: imagecopy() basically slices a specified rectangle from one image and paste into another. it will not flip that slice for you. You have to extract single lines in a loop and paste them into the new position in the destination image.

Comment: Hi Marc, that sounds very difficult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to share the answer some years later... :)

Change:

```
imagecopy($output, $input, 8, 20, 4, 20, 4, 12)
```

To:

```
imagecopyresampled($output, $input, 8, 20, (8 - 1), 20, 4, 12, 0 - 4, 12);
```

Which will flip the part of the image horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

[Found here](http://www.planetsourcecode.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=1876&lngWId=8):

```
//**************************************
// Name: Flip Image with GD
// Description:These are two easy to use functions that will flip an image, either horizontally or vertically. Just create an image, then execute one of these functions on the image resource. The image resource is passed by reference to the functions, so no return values are sent from the functions. Example shown in code.
// By: Ryand833
//
//This code is copyrighted and has// limited warranties.Please see http://www.Planet-Source-Code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=1876&lngWId=8//for details.//**************************************

<?php
function flipVertical(&$img) {
 $size_x = imagesx($img);
 $size_y = imagesy($img);
 $temp = imagecreatetruecolor($size_x, $size_y);
 $x = imagecopyresampled($temp, $img, 0, 0, 0, ($size_y-1), $size_x, $size_y, $size_x, 0-$size_y);
 if ($x) {
$img = $temp;
 }
 else {
die("Unable to flip image");
 }
}
function flipHorizontal(&$img) {
 $size_x = imagesx($img);
 $size_y = imagesy($img);
 $temp = imagecreatetruecolor($size_x, $size_y);
 $x = imagecopyresampled($temp, $img, 0, 0, ($size_x-1), 0, $size_x, $size_y, 0-$size_x, $size_y);
 if ($x) {
$img = $temp;
 }
 else {
die("Unable to flip image");
 }
}
$myimage = imagecreatefromjpeg("psclogo.jpg");
flipHorizontal($myimage);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($myimage);
?>
```

Using this idea as a starting point, what you are going to do is call `imagecopyresample` on each slice of the image (as you have above), utilizing the height/width to reverse the slices.

Then you would call `imagecopy` on each "resampled" slice to copy it into your new, working image.

Comment: Sorry i cant use that, i just edited my question with my script so you could see why

Comment: Sure, it doesn't solve the entire algorithm; it does capture the problem. The comments by @Marc_B are spot on; you need to use the image's height/width properties and subtract in order to flip the slices. (I'll add some notes)

Answer (score 0):

See the image_flip function in comments at http://php.net/imagecopy

**edit** here is the exact link: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php#85992

**edit 2** To implement it into your code, just use the line

```
$flippedOutput = ImageFlip($output,IMAGE_FLIP_HORIZONTAL);
```

Comment: I have, dont know how to implement it to my script :)

Comment: Basicaly the same solution as what I pasted below; both utilize `imagecopyresampled` though, which won't work in his case.

Comment: Arg, let me elaborate: this won't work in his case if I understand the comment "some parts need to be flipped" correctly (@2by-does this imply not all parts as I assumed?)

Comment: Dont know if anyone will be answering now, but I still haven´t found a solution nearly two years after :) No  only one part of the imagecopyresampled needs to be flipped

Comment: @2by - oh, what an archeologist you are :-) I will have a look on this by the end of the week then.